# Firebase putFile - Where to (de)activate the upload button?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to find the correct place to temporarily deactivate and then reactivate the upload button, so a user doesn't click it multiple times while waiting for the upload.
This is my approach so far:

```
private void uploadFile() {

    if (mImageUri != null) {
        StorageReference sR = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        mButtonUpload.setClickable(false);

        sR.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);

                        mButtonUpload.setClickable(true);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

However, according to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener), the `onCompleteListener` will only be called if there as a request at all. So it is possible that it is not called (for example if there is no internet connection). So where is the appropriate place to reactivate my button?

**EDIT:**

What do you guys think of storing the StorageTask in a member variable and then checking on button click? I noticed that upload tasks still remain in a queue when there is no connection, so just reactivating the button would be not a good approach.

```
 mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
```

and

```
mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                uploadFile();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of disabling button try to show `progress bar`, it will improve your UX.

Comment: I do that, but that doesnt keep the user from spamming the button

Comment: Check answer, and let me know if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

To disable user interaction while `progress bar` is in visible state. You can do it in two ways,

**First --** Either simply set `android:clickable = "true"` in your `progress bar` xml. For example,

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

**Second --** Or disable user interaction programmatically in your java when `progress bar` is visible. For example,

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To enable again user interaction use,

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

**Edit --** How to catch `FirebaseNetworkException`. Try this,

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(mAuthCredential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        // task complete succesfully

                    }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                      if (exception instanceof FirebaseNetworkException){                                             
                            // no network connection
                      } else {
                            // any other exception occur
                      }
              }
            });
```

For more info about `Firebase Exception` check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseNetworkException

Comment: Blocking the button is not the problem, the problem is where to reactivate it. OnCompleteListener is only called if there is an internet connection.

Comment: Check answer now @FlorianWalther

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it when I'm back home

Comment: Yup bro approve it and give a plus one, if it helps you.

Comment: The problem is that onComplete is never called without a connection

Comment: Yup you have to addOnFailureListener, where you can catch FirebaseNetworkException.

Comment: Well I noticed that it queues up the uploads if there is no internet connection, so just making the button clickable again is not the right approach. I didnt know that before, thats my mistake. I think my new approach which I edited into my question is better.